# Python: GDAL ERROR - Access window out of range in RasterIO()

Tags: python, error-handling, expect, gdal

i have this error problem with GDAL/

```
INPUT_raster = "E:\myraster.asc"
ds = gdal.Open(INPUT_raster, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
data = band.ReadAsArray(9658, 11599, 1, 1)
ERROR 5: E:\myraster.asc, band 1: Access window out of range in RasterIO().  Requested
(9658,11599) of size 1x1 on raster of 9658x16934.
```

is it possible to use try: and expect: to avoid this error?

I would appreciate your comments/suggestions.

Regards,
Gianni

Answer (score 2):

Try/expect dont avoid errors, they handle them.

You are trying to read data from a position which doesnt exist in your raster. The x dimension is 9658 elements large, if you want the outer most element you should use 9657 because the indexing starts at zero.

So use:

```
data = band.ReadAsArray(9657, 11599, 1, 1)
```

or for the last x position:

```
data = band.ReadAsArray(ds.RasterXSize-1, 11599, 1, 1)
```

Comment: thanks but suppose you have several points and some points lay inside the image